# Is there a way to take the `Title Text` from the Google Sheets cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to take the `Title Text` from the Google Sheets cell?

So whenever I change the cell string then it should appear in the Chart automatically.

For example: I have `May - 2021` in cell A1. Can I reference this in `Title Text`, like using `=A1` or `=Sheet1!A1`? But it does not work.

[image]

I got this code, but how do I reference the cell into the code?

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Charts').addItem('Update', 'myFunction').addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('Summary!Q123', sheet.getActiveCell().getValue() || 'Summary!Q123')
  .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it is not possible to link a cell value as `title`, there is a trick that may solve your problem by creating a merge cell, `camouflage`, as the title. Then it will be changed, based on the text value you enter :)

[image]

**Script:**

You may use the following script to update the title by referring to `A3` every time you execute the code. Basically, you are almost correct:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var newtitle = sheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue();

  var charts = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var chart = charts.modify()
    .setOption('title', newtitle)
    .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart)

  var scnCharts = sheet.getCharts()[1];
  var chart2 = scnCharts.modify()
    .setOption('title', newtitle)
    .build()
  sheet.updateChart(chart2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This trick is nice but it will not work in my case. I have updated the code in my question where i am trying to referencing the cell but its not working.

Comment: ok, let me have a look how to use script to update it, maybe get back to you tomorrow or other expert may help you :)

Comment: I got this too but unable to fetch how to reference the cell `Q125` [Link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114561/set-title-of-currently-selected-chart-from-named-cell)

Comment: See my edited answer, it will give you and idea on how store `cell value as variable` then use it to update title :)

Comment: Thank you very much its working like charm. Is it possible to link `Two Charts` with the code it is working for single. Because i need to update same title in two charts

Comment: I think it is possible, by adding  `var charts1 = sheet.getCharts()[1]` and use the same method then shall work. Basically `getcharts()` will return all the `charts` within the sheet, each chart is referred by the index value, start from `0,1,2, so on`. So you first chart is `getcharts()[0]`, second chart is `getcharts()[1]`. Give it a try, if cannot I will update again .

Comment: I have tried with `var charts = sheet.getCharts()[0][1];` then `var charts = sheet.getCharts();` but its not working can you please update the answer. It will be great help.

Comment: I did it by adding `for (var i in charts) {
    var chart = charts[i].modify()` Thanks  @Kin Siang

Comment: See my edited answer, it now work for multiple chart now :)

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for Thanks @Kin Siang

Answer (score 0):

I've seen somewhere a suggestion to make the chart background transparent and to show the cells below it (you can colour-match cell borders with cell colour to hide them), and I'm currently using that approach. But instead of making the main chart transparent, I'm creating a bar chart based on one cell (You have to merge two cells then the chart works), modifying it and removing a background from it, minimalising scale etc. As a result, I have the X-axis name based on the text from the cell.

[image]